# TwoWay data binding with Realm in master/details views

Tags: c#, realm

I am working on a project with master/detail views similar to the `QuickJournal` example code. The master view is `GridView` bound to a collection, and the detail view is bound to an individual item in the collection.

When I navigate from the master view to the detail view, I am starting a new `Transaction`. If I make changes to the detail view and save the item (commit the transaction), it will navigate back to the master view and everything is fine.

My problem is that if I do not make any changes to the detail view and try to navigate back to the master page using the back button, I get an exception **"Cannot set values outside transaction"**. I have tried a couple different ways:

1) `_trans.Dispose();` in the detail page `OnNavigatingFrom` handler (described above)

2) `_trans.Rollback();` in the detail page same as above

3) leave the transaction open when navigating back; this doesn't throw an exception when navigating back to the master page, but instead throws an exception when trying to go back to the detail page again since there is already an open transaction

4) setting the current databound item to `null` before navigating back to master view; this causes different problems because you can't bind to `null`

I have seen that there is a `Realm.DataBinding` package that is supposed to automatically handle transactions as needed, but I cannot find any examples of its usage. Is there a way around this issue without making a duplicate copy of the object in question and using that in the detail view, and just throwing it out if you don't make any changes??

Comment: One thing I thought of that I haven't tried yet, is to rollback/dispose the transaction from the master page when navigating back. I do not have the code in front of me right now to try that approach, but thought I'd mention it here if anyone has feedback on that as well.

Comment: `Realm.DataBinding` handles transactions automatically for Xamarin.Forms bindings, but isn't well suited for a UI where you want to have a Save/Cancel UX. There's nothing particular about using it - it's all automatic, which is why there are only a few example. Here's a blog post that showcases some of the UX: https://academy.realm.io/posts/nikola-irinchev-observable-models-with-realm-for-xamarin/

Comment: My guess is that you're disposing of the transaction too early and the binding engine tries to change something after that. Probably committing/disposing in the master view would solve that.

Comment: @NikolaIrinchev I was thinking along those same lines. The exception isn't thrown until back on the master page when trying to bind the collection again. As shown in the `QuickJournal` sample, is it best to use `Dispose()` on the transaction, or explicitly roll it back?

Comment: Also, I should mention, that this is a UWP application, so the `Xamarin.Forms` data binding probably works differently.

Comment: `Rollback` and `Dispose` work the same way, so doesn't really matter. Unfortunately, for UWP the automatic mechanism in `Realm.DataBinding` will not work, so your approach is the only viable one. Do you have two-way bindings on the master page? If you can share the project, it's probably best to open a Github issue and we'll investigate.